# Json file no anexa un usuario en una nueva linea

Tags: python-3.x, json

En este código busco crear un nuevo usuario y agregarlo a un json file existente, pero cuando guardo el usuario nuevo me reemplaza el que ya estaba en el json file.

**# Diccionario vacío**
**usuarios = {}**
**# Crear un json file**
json_usuarios = json.dumps(usuarios,indent= 4)
with open('usuarios.json','w',) as file:
file.write(json_usuarios)
file.close()

```
**# Crea un nuevo usuario**
def newUser():
    **# Pedir datos**
    flag = True
    while flag:   
        **userName = input('Digita un nombre de usuario>> ') 
        userPass = input('Digita una contraseña>> ')
        repPass = input('Confirma la contraseña>> ')
        if userPass != repPass:
            print("Contraseña no coinciden!")
            print("Intenta de nuevo")
            userPass = input('Digita una contraseña>> ')
            repPass = input('Confirma la contraseña>> ')
        else:
            print('Usuario creado!')
            time.sleep(1)
            flag = False** 

    **# Anexar el nuevo usurio al diccionario en el json file existente**
    user_dict = {}
    user_dict['username'] = userName
    user_dict['password'] = userPass
    with open('usuarios.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(user_dict,f,indent=4)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Eso es por que estás reemplazando un json anterior por otro. Tenés que abrir el json anterior, procesarlo, añadir el nuevo usuario y volverlo a guardar.

Comment: No veía el error, Gracias!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque fue resuelto en los comentarios.